# Subset a string in POSIX shell

Tags: sh, posix

I have a variable set in the following format:

```bash
var1="word1 word2 word3"
```

Is it possible to subset/delete one of the space-delimited word portably? What I want to archive is something like this:
when `--ignore` option is supplied with the following argument

```bash
$ cmd --ignore word1 # case 1
$ cmd --ignore "word1 word2" # case2
```

I want the `var1` changes to have only the following value

```bash
"word2 word3" # case1
"word3" #case2
```

If there is no way to achieve above described, is there a way to improve the efficiency of the following for loop? (The `$var1` is in a for loop so my alternative thought to achieve similar was having following code)

```bash
# while loop to get argument from options
# argument of `--ignore` is assigned to `$sh_ignore`
for i in $var1
do
  # check $i in $sh_ignore instead of other way around 
  # to avoid unmatch when $sh_ignore has more than 1 word
  if ! echo "$sh_ignore" | grep "$i";
  then
    # normal actions
  else
    # skipped
  fi
done
```

-------Update-------

After looking around and reading the comment by @chepner I now temporarily using following code (and am looking for improvement):

```bash
sh_ignore=''
while :; do
  case
    # some other option handling
    --ignore)
      if [ "$2" ]; then
          sh_ignore=$2
          shift
        else
          # defined `die` as print err msg + exit 1
          die 'ERROR: "--ignore" requires a non-empty option argument.'
        fi
        ;;
    # handling if no arg is supplied to --ignore
    # handling -- and unknown opt
  esac
  shift
done

if [ -n "$sh_ignore" ]; then
  for d in $sh_ignore
  do
    var1="$(echo "$var1" | sed -e "s,$d,,")"
  done
fi

# for loop with trimmed $var1 as downstream
for i in $var1
do
  # normal actions
done
```

Comment: I found I can use a for loop and substitute with `sed` when handling the option, but I'm not sure if it will cause any security issue. Also I'm not sure if `sed -e` behaves the same across system

Comment: `sed -e` is part of the POSIX standard, so it should be portable (as long as you are using POSIX-compliant systems).

Comment: Using a space-separated string as a list is not *ideal*, as you are probably aware, but the only workaround would be to hijack the positional parameters (`set -- "word1" "word2" "word3"`) if possible. You might consider using `expr` to do regular-expression matching instead of piping to `grep`.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure if it would be applicable to my script, but `var1` is a predefined string (I can still change that easily for now). I used it in a for loop to check if certain cmd exist or needs to be installed. That's why sometimes certain cmd needs to be skipped, when the related program is installed but modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method might be:

```
var1=$(echo "$var1" |
       tr ' ' '\n' |
       grep -Fxv -e "$(echo "$sh_ignore" | tr ' ' '\n')" |
       tr '\n' ' ')
```

Note: this will leave a trailing blank, which can be trimmed off via `var1=${var1% }`